# Error: [$injector:modulerr] - angular confirm

Tags: angularjs

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=contactsApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dangular-confirm%26p1

I am trying to use angular confirm. But it gives above error as soon as I use it.
Following is my html code where I have defined my ng-app and ng-controller:

**Contacts.html**

```
<div ng-app="contactsApp" class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
        <div class="col-sm-12 padding-0">  <h2 class="text-center"> Contacts</h2>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading c-list">
                    <span class="title">Contacts</span>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload-contacts" href="#upload-contacts" data-placement="top" title="Add Contact">
                            <span class="title "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</span>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**contacts.js:**

```
var mycontacts = angular.module('contactsApp',['angular-confirm']);

        mycontacts.controller('contactsCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$window, $confirm) {

            $scope.sendInvitation = function (el) {
               var email = "simer@gmail.com"  
                $confirm({text: 'Do you want to delete this record?', title: 'Confirmation', ok: 'Yes', cancel: 'No'}).then(function() {
                    $http.get('/sendinvitation/',{params:{"email" : email},headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
                    .success(function(response)
                    {
                        $window.location.reload();
                    });
                });
            }

            });
```

Once I remove ['angular-confirm'] from ng-app and $confirm from ng-controller my application works fine.

following are files I included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-confirm.js"></script>

        <script src="/djangular/js/django-angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/frontend/myContacts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will the order matter? Adding angular-confirm first and then angular next? 
Do you think it matters?

Comment: I think you should include angular-confirm after angular.min

Comment: Are you missing Angular-UI-Bootstrap as angular-confirm uses bootstrap ?

Comment: @meetkichu Can you refer some link. I have sorted the order of file inclusion but I dont know about "angular-ui-bootstrap". I have instead included "ui-bootstrap-tpls"

Comment: @G_S and Roman I have corrected the order.

Comment: Are you still getting same error?
and 
I think ui-bootstrap-tpls is itself angular-ui-bootstrap. @meetkichu Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes The error is gone now.Thanks!! :D